# Publish results of an API call to a collection in Meteor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, collections

I'm attempting to make a simple RSS feed reader that will allow a user to enter a url in a search bar and display the results using Meteor and React. In my current set up, I have a SearchBar component with a function that makes a call to the meteor method on the server. How can I store the return of the API call in a client side collection? I've seen some examples on using publish and subscribe to do this, but haven't been able to follow. My goal is to save this data in a client side collection so I can access it from any components that will need it, and not have to render subsequent components through the SearchBar component's render method. This is how I currently have it set up:

**feeds.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';
import parser from 'rss-parser';

if(Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        getFeed(url) {
            this.unblock();
            const feed = {
                title: '',
                entries: []
            };
            try {
                console.log('trying to get url');
                const response = HTTP.get(url);
                parser.parseString(response.content, function(err, parsed) {
                  feed.title = parsed.feed.title;
                  parsed.feed.entries.forEach(function(entry) {
                    feed.entries.push(entry);
                  })
                });
                console.log(feed.title);
                return feed;
            } catch(e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**SearchBar.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker';

import FeedList from './FeedList';

export default class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            results: null,
            url: ''
        }
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        const { url } = this.state;

        e.preventDefault();

        const response = Meteor.call('getFeed', url, (err, res) => {
            if(!err) {
                this.setState({
                    results:res.entries
                });
                console.log(this.state.results);
            } else {
                console.log(err.reason);
            }
        });
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            url: e.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a URL" value={this.state.url} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}/>
                    <button type="submit">Get Feed</button>
                </form>
                {this.state.results ? <FeedList feedItems={this.state.results}/> : <p>Load a feed</p>}
            </div>
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: A typical pattern for this is for a cron job to populate a collection that is published to the client and rendered there. Then this whole process can happen transparently for the user with automatic updates. Since it's the server that's doing the `HTTP.get()` a client-side collection isn't quite as convenient as it is in other use cases. In any event, I've previously published a [tuorialt on client side collections](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-meteor-local-collections-to-support-browser-based-cryptography) that you might find useful.

Comment: I'd suggest using the low level publication API to poll the endpoint using a setInterval and update the 'feeds' collection (or whatever you want to name it). There's a basic example in the Meteor guide: https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#custom-publication

Comment: Also a more specific example here, complete with the interval: https://forums.meteor.com/t/best-way-to-handle-a-3rd-party-endpoint/7017/2

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, I'll check these out!

Comment: Would it also be possible to just define a client-side collection and store the data returned from the method in that collection? Assuming I want to keep the current structure of the app and just use the method call and not publish

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't get the feed on the server at all. Get it on the client, and save it using a local collection defined like:

```
let localCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null)
```

Regarding the comments:

> A typical pattern for this is for a cron job to populate a collection that is published to the client and rendered there.

This is going to be way over-engineered for your needs, and it's commonly regarded as a canonically wrong answer.

Comment: One could do that... but think about having credentials for the api-call that the client has no permission for (my case). It then needs to happen on the server.